# In Log4Net all specified log folders are created but logging is not working for File Appender

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, rollingfileappender, fileappender

I'm using Castle with Log4Net. All folders were created but logging information is not written to a text file.

Here is the config:

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
<add key="log4net.Internal.Error" value="true"/>
<add key="log4net.Internal.Info" value="true"/>
<add key="log4net.Internal.Fatal" value="true"/>
<add key="log4net.Internal.Warn" value="true"/>


<appender name="debugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="DEBUG" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  <file value="..\\..\\LOGS\\DEBUG\\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <DatePattern value="yyyy\\\\MM\\\\dd\\\\yyyyMMdd'_debug.txt'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <!--<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>`

<logger name="Log">
  <appender-ref ref="errorAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="infoAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="debugAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="warningAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="fatalAppender" />
</logger>`
```

I'm using console application for this, and the Main method will start like this:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

And everyone has permission to write, read all files in LOGS folders.

Comment: <file value="C:\\Logs\\Debug\\LogFileName.log" />
Try using the full path name and check.

Comment: where have you added XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config")); this line ? Under Application_Start ?

Comment: Varun , this code block is in Program.cs first code. Is it right ?

Comment: It is ok to add it anywhere so that your configuration is read. Better if you add at the application start under global.asax

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial
I found this nice tute. I think it will be helpful to you

Comment: I dont have any global.asax because my app is console application.But all folders was properly created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your same configuration of course with little modification which you can try

I created a console application as yours:

Here is my Entry point:

```
public class Program
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log
      = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("..\\..\\log4net.config"));
            log.Debug("Hi this is DEBUG from logging");
            log.Info("This is information from logger");
            log.Error("This is Error from logger");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

And here is the configuration I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <section name="log4net"

     type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
            log4net"/>
    </configSections>
  <log4net>
      <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender,log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} 
    [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="DEBUG" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="debugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="DEBUG" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
      <file value="..\\..\\LOGS\\DEBUG\\" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <DatePattern value="yyyy\\\\MM\\\\dd\\\\yyyyMMdd'_debug.txt'" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <!--<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />-->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
      <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <!--<appender-ref ref="DebugOutputAppender" />-->
      <appender-ref ref="debugAppender" />
    </root>
   </log4net>
</configuration>
```

You can notice I have ***added*** **Console** appender to check whether the logging is working as expected on the console before checking the log file.

**Note**: With the same configuration as yours I was not able to log any information in Console as well as file although the folder and the file were getting created without any issues.

The change I did is, added a **root** level element as pasted in the above configuration snippet.
You need to have one root section to house your top-level logger references. These are the loggers that inherit information from your base logger (root).

I have ***removed*** the additional loggers which you have used.

Sometimes you will want to know more about a particular part of your application. log4net anticipated this by allowing you to specify additional logger references beyond just the root logger. For example, here is an additional logger to log to the console messages that occur inside the **OtherClass** class object:

```
<logger name="Log4NetTest.OtherClass">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Use it if you are really sure on this.

Good tutorial to start with log4net is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial).

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Remove <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" /> line from the appender and in root level edit
<root>
      <level value="ALL" />
This should work

Comment: Im using your config file , and my app is quartz.net with castle windsor.And quartz.net debugging logs all in txt file.I dont know what is happening. Here is the log and config file both.
[link]https://ufile.io/1text

Comment: Still not working ?? Have you tried using ConsoleAppender whether logging is working fine or not ?

Comment: Did you download the file ? Its writing all quartz.net logs.I dont want it , i just want write all my logs.

here is the console log. ==> 

[Console Log](https://ibb.co/b6tYfo)

Comment: <logger name="QuartzService.Folders.Interfaces.IQuartzInitializer">
      <level value="OFF" />
      <appender-ref ref="debugAppender"/>
    </logger>

Uncomment <logger> and set level to OFF.

Comment: I make this but it doesnt work dude :) , nevermind this is make me crazy.Thanks for your help :)